Using multi-indexing to find all combinations matching a certain pattern
I need to write an algorithm that takes N points, and outputs all the possible 3-stars and triangles that are formed by the points. Here's an example for clarification.
Let N = 4, then I have 4 choose 2 = 6 distances, the set
{(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3)}
We define a 3-star as 3 distances that all share 1 index. For example {(0,1),(1,2),(1,3)} is a star, but {(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)} is not. A triangle is defined as three distances where the first and second, second and third, and third and first pairs share an index, for example {(0,1),(1,2),(0,2)}, but not {(0,1),(1,2),(1,3)}.
I need to take N and output a list of all such 3-stars, and all triangles. They can be in the same list or in different lists for the output.
Is there a fast way to do this? I'm using python, so have access to the pandas multi-index which I think may be useful.
So far I've tried using a very naive approach, where I just loop 6 variables through 1 to NC2 and use an indicator function to pick out all the triangles. I've also managed to pick out the 3-stars using multi-index:
edges = list(itertools.combinations(range(N),2))
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(edges)

# all 3 pairs share 1 index
for i in range(c):
    core = mi[i]
    arr = np.bitwise_xor(mi.get_level_values(0) == core[0], mi.get_level_values(1) == core[1])
    for (outer1, outer2) in itertools.combinations(mi[arr], 2):
        if outer1[0] in outer2 or outer1[1] in outer2:
            print(core, outer1, outer2)

But this duplicates each of the stars.
I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I just can't seem to get my head around it, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

It is unclear why you specify the point locations.  The stars, for example, do not seem to need all three distances to be equal, or less than some value.  So, why bother with the locations ( x,y, values ) since they do not seem to have any significance.  Dropping the locations will make it easier to think about this problem which is pure combinatorics.

@ravenspoint to clarify, the points are arbitrary, i.e. 0,1,2,3 are just the 'labels' of the points, so I am just asking for the best way to select the pairs (i.e. pure combinatorics!)

Oh I misunderstood.  (0,1) is not a location but a connection between points0 and 1.  Suggest you use less confusing labels, e.g. a,b,c ...

The stars are given by all permutations of 4 elements. The first element of the permutation is the centre of the star and the remaining 3 points are the outside of the star. You can eliminate the duplicates by ensuring that the last 3 elements of each permutation are in a given order (i.e. ascending order).
The triangles are given by all combinations of 3 elements. The triangle is formed by joining the first to the second then second to third and, finally, third back to the first element.
Like this:
from itertools import permutations, combinations

N = 4
stars = [{(a, b), (a, c), (a, d)} for a, b, c, d in permutations(range(N), 4) if b < c < d]
triangles = [{(a, b), (b, c), (c, a)} for a, b, c in combinations(range(N), 3)]

The stars are:
[{(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)},
 {(1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3)},
 {(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3)},
 {(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)}]

The triangles are:
[{(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)},
 {(0, 1), (1, 3), (3, 0)},
 {(0, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0)},
 {(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)}]


Or, equivalently, if you want to use combinations to generate the stars:
stars = [
    {(w, x), (w, y), (w, z)}
    for a, b, c, d in combinations(range(N), 4)
    for w, x, y, z in (
        (a, b, c, d),
        (b, a, c, d),
        (c, a, b, d),
        (d, a, b, c),
    )
]


I didn't know you could use list comprehensions like that! Thank you.
